# Problem with repeated objects while importing JSON into Google BigQuery

Tags: javascript, json, google-bigquery

I have been trying to manually upload the JSON into BigQuery, but I get the following error message.

```
Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Repeated field must be imported as a JSON array. Field: custom_fields.value.
```

I already converted the file into newline delimited JSON, so that is not the problem.
When looking at the custom_field.value from the error I get this:

```
$ cat convert2working.json | jq .custom_fields[].value
0
"Basics of information security\n"
"2021"
```

The problem seems to be that the custom_fields.value has different data types.

**How can I "homogenize" those data types? or do you have another solution.** I would prefer to stay in javascript

Here is a shortened version of my JSON code:

```
{
    "id": "example",
    "custom_fields": [
        {
            "id": "example",
            "name": "Interval",
            "type": "drop_down",
            "type_config": {
                "default": 0,
                "placeholder": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "example",
                        "name": "yearly",
                        "color": null,
                        "orderindex": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            "date_created": "1611228211303",
            "hide_from_guests": false,
            "value": 0,
            "required": false
        },
        {
            "id": "example",
            "name": "Description",
            "type": "text",
            "type_config": {},
            "date_created": "1611228263444",
            "hide_from_guests": false,
            "value": "Basics of information security\n",
            "required": false
        },
        {
            "id": "example",
            "name": "Year",
            "type": "number",
            "type_config": {},
            "date_created": "1611228275285",
            "hide_from_guests": false,
            "value": "2021",
            "required": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should share your current javascript code with people, so they can have a better understanding of your problem and help you to solve this.

Comment: I don't have a javascript code yet, since I wanted to see if I can upload it manually into BigQuery first.

Comment: I'm just a reviewer of your post and I've never heard about BigQuery. But my understanding of the message returned is that you defined the field value inside BigQuery as a repeated field and so, google is expecting your data in `value` to be an array and not a string. So I would say : it looks like a problem in the data structure definition in big query. I think you can solve your problem by changing the field configuration in it or by wrapping your `value` between `[]` e.g. `"value": ["2021"],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize your data structure so that BigQuery is able to [auto-detect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) a consistent schema. Because the `value` property is once a `number` and once a `string`, this auto-detection fails.

There are multiple ways to normalize your data. I'm not 100% sure which way will work best for BigQuery, which claims to analyze up to the first 100 rows for schema auto-detection.

The first attempt is to put different types of values into different fields

```js
const fields = data.custom_fields.map(x => {

    const f = {
        id: x.id,
    name: x.name
  };
  
  f[x.type] = x.value;
  
  return f;
});
```

This will yield:

```js
[{
  id: "example",
  name: "Interval",
  value_drop_down: 0
}, {
  id: "example",
  name: "Description",
  value_text: "Basics of information security↵"
}, {
  id: "example",
  name: "Year",
  value_number: "2021"
}]
```

I'm not sure if this is a structure where BigQuery can reliably merge the inferred type schema for fields, because it might e.g. only encounter `value_number` in the first 100 rows, and will therefore not handle `value_dropdown`.

A more reliable approach (assuming you know all the different values of `type`) is to transform the records explicitly into the same structure. This also has the advantage of being able to run any specialized transformations on field values (such as conversions, lookups etc.)

```js
const fields2 = data.custom_fields.map(x => ({
    id: x.id,
    name: x.name,
    value_text: x.type === 'text' ? x.value : null,
    value_number: x.type === 'number' ? parseInt(x.value, 10) : null,
    value_dropdown: x.type === 'drop_down' ? x.type_config.options.find(o => o.orderindex === x.value).name : null
  })
);
```

You might have to make some of the transform logic a bit more robust depending on your data (e.g. if values are optional or can be empty). Using your example data this transformation yields:

```js
[{
  "id": "example",
  "name": "Interval",
  "value_text": null,
  "value_number": null,
  "value_dropdown": "yearly",
  "value_drop_down": 0
}, {
  "id": "example",
  "name": "Description",
  "value_text": "Basics of information security\n",
  "value_number": null,
  "value_dropdown": null
}, {
  "id": "example",
  "name": "Year",
  "value_text": null,
  "value_number": "2021",
  "value_dropdown": null
}]
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbgstveh/2/) where you can play around with this code.